# alexa "undefined" to no response on "repromptSpeech"

Tags: javascript, undefined, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create a skill of facts with this structure:

> **User**: "Alexa asks my skill a fact"
>
> **Skill**: "here is your fact" "are we going on?"
>
> **User**: "yes"
>
> **Skill**: "here is your fact" "are we going on?"
>
> **User**: "no"
>
> **Skill**: "End of session, goodbye"

so far so good, but if the user does not answer anything the skill says `"undefined" "there was a problem with the requested skill"` and she leaves.

> **User**: "Alexa asks my skill a fact"
>
> **Skill**: "here is your fact" "are we going on?"
>
> **User**: ""
>
> **Skill**: "undefined" "there was a problem with the requested skill"

is there a pre-build intent to handle this kind of case?

I need your help.

thank you in advance
Envoyer des commentaires
Historique
Enregistré
Communauté

Answer (score 0):

Alexa should deliver a `SessionEndedRequest` whenever the user does not reply.

[Handle Requests Sent by Alexa (SessionEndedRequest)](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/handle-requests-sent-by-alexa.html#sessionendedrequest):

> Your service receives a SessionEndedRequest when a currently open session is closed for one of the following reasons:
>
> - The user says "exit" or "quit".
> - The user does not respond or says something that does not match an intent defined in your voice interface while the device is listening for the user's response.
> - An error occurs.

So you should be handling that as you would handle the `LaunchRequest` or `IntentRequest`.